# Why am I getting Debug assertion failed after strcpy_s?

Tags: c++, sockets, networking

im just starting to learn about sockets and i have been given this code, and i have to make the port lookup logic work. But the problem is i keep getting this run time error and I dont know why?

```
// portlookup.cpp
// Given a service name, this program displays the corresponding port number.

#include <iostream>
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
#include <winsock2.h>
using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    char    service[80];    // This string contains name of desired service
    struct  servent *pse;   // pointer to service information entry
    short   port;           // Port # (in Network Byte Order) of desired service

    if (argc < 2)
    {
        cout << "Please specify a service." << endl;

    }

    strcpy_s(service, sizeof(service), argv[1]);

    WORD wVersion = 0x0202;
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult = WSAStartup(wVersion, &wsaData);  // Returns zero if successful
    if (iResult != 0) {
        cout << "Insufficient resources to startup WINSOCK." << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    port = htons( (u_short) atoi(service)); // 1st try to convert string to integer
    if (port == 0) {                        // if that doesn't work, call service function
        pse = getservbyname(service,NULL);
        if (pse) {
            port = pse->s_port;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Invalid service request." << endl;
            return INVALID_SOCKET;
        }
    }

    cout << "Service: " << service << endl;
    cout << "Port:    " << htons(port) << endl;

}
```

Comment: after the first use of strcpy, it says Debug assertion failed

Comment: Nope, I tried Strncpy it didn't work

Comment: One remark: the output of the port number should probably be `ntohs`, because `htons` will convert to network byte order. However, in both branches you will have port in big endian byte order.

Comment: What does your command line look like?

Comment: Im using Visual C++, when i click "start without debugginng, its then i get the debug assertion.

Comment: That's your problem. argv[1] is NULL.

Comment: You also should return if argc < 2.

Comment: So I should set it to the entire contents of argv?

Comment: No, you need to run from a command line: <progname> <service to look up>. argv is the array of command line arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem appears to be that you aren't passing a command line, you check argc < 2, but when it is < 2 you execute the strcpy_s anyway.

In Visual Studio, Got to the Project Properties dialog, from there go to the *Debugging* page
and add the service name to *Command Arguments*

And fix your argument checking code

```
if (argc < 2)
{
    //cout << "Please specify a service." << endl;
    cerr << "error: no service specified." << endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE; // return some non-zero value to indicate failure.
}
```

Comment: @Richard: No idea. back in my day vi was the _advanced_ editor. and debugging was printf ;D

Comment: @John: You mean that vi *isn't* the advanced editor? When did emacs win?

Comment: @Richard: emacs? we didn't have emacs, we had vi and ed.

Comment: EXIT_FAILURE or 1 make better default return codes than 42. :)

Comment: @Roger: is there a standard exit code for 'your not using me right?'

Comment: @John: The C and C++ standards only provide EXIT_SUCCESS and EXIT_FAILURE.  Either 1 or 2 is commonly used for that (2 slightly more common), but there's no consensus common enough for me to say it's standard.

Comment: While you're at it, using stderr (cerr/clog) for those error messages is better than stdout. :P

Answer (score 2):

You need to start your program with an argument. The line `strcpy_s(service, sizeof(service),argv[1]);` assumes you've given the program 1 argument, which will be stored in argv[1].

If you don't run it with any arguments, argv[1] will be NULL and your program will crash.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to exit if no parameter is specified.

```
if (argc < 2) 
{ 
    cout << "Please specify a service." << endl; 
    return 0; // exit! 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

also,

```
port = htons( (u_short) atoi(service));
...
cout << htons(port);
```